# Differentiation of a function

Tags: derivatives

We need to find out the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of the following:

$x^m$$y^n$=$(x+y)^{m+n}$

- I know how to differentiate the function and on solving we get $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{y}{x}$. But we notice that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is independent of values of $m$ and $n$. So what I did was again starting the problem from start but this time substituting any arbitrary values of $m$ and $n$, like $m$=$n$=$1$ (lets say). That is we get $xy$=$(x+y)^2$. Now opening the square bracket and solving we get

$x^2+y^2+xy=0$

So $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{-2x-y}{2y+x}$

But the answer should be $\frac{y}{x}$.Whats wrong in assuming arbitrary values of $m$ and $n$ if the answer dosen't depend upon values of $m$ and $n$.Please help.

**How I got $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{y}{x}$**?

$x+y$=$x^\frac{m}{m+n}$$y^\frac{m}{m+n}$

$ln(x+y)$=$\frac{m(ln(x))}{(m+n)}$+$\frac{n(ln(y))}{(m+n)}$

Differentiating we get

$\frac{1}{x+y}$.$(1+\frac{dy}{dx})$=$\frac{m}{(m+n)x}$+$\frac{n}{(m+n)y}\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}(\frac{1}{x+y}-\frac{n}{(m+n)y})$=$\frac{m}{(m+n)x}-\frac{1}{x+y}$

Just rearrange and you are done $\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: To me your result seems to be right. Why do you think that $dy/dx = y/x$?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the equation $x^2+y^2+xy=0$ only exists at $(0,0)$, so its probably a bad example.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I made a correction.

Comment: Hm, it does appear you are right, though it takes quite a bit of work to get there.  And upon solving the DE, you get $y=ax$ by the way.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt No need to solve the DE by the way . See edits.

Comment: Okay.  Then I suppose we are done :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Hey but please tell me whats wrong in assuming arbitrary values of m,n? Equation exists only at $(0,0)$ so its not working or there is some fault in my reasoning?

Comment: You need to choose values of m,n such that the function actually exists lol.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt OK.Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure how you got $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac yx$.  You should instead have

$$\frac d{dx}x^my^n=mx^{m-1}y^n+nx^my^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\frac d{dx}(x+y)^{m+n}=(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

Put these two together and we get

$$mx^{m-1}y^n+nx^my^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}=(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

Expand a bit:

$$mx^{m-1}y^n+nx^my^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}=(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}+(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Group the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ terms:

$$\left(nx^my^{n-1}-(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}-mx^{m-1}y^n$$

Divide both sides:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}-mx^{m-1}y^n}{nx^my^{n-1}-(m+n)(x+y)^{m+n-1}}$$

and I'm fairly certain this does not equal $\frac yx$.  It does simplify a little though:

$$(x+y)^{m+n-1}=\frac{x^my^n}{x+y}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(m+n)\frac{x^my^n}{x+y}-mx^{m-1}y^n}{nx^my^{n-1}-(m+n)\frac{x^my^n}{x+y}}$$

Divide the numerator and denominator by $x^my^n$ to get

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{m+n}{x+y}-mx^{-1}}{ny^{-1}-\frac{m+n}{x+y}}$$

Now simplify the fractions:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(m+n)xy-my(x+y)}{nx(x+y)-(m+n)xy}$$

Expand and cancel like terms:

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{nxy-my^2}{nx^2-mxy}$$

Comment: See the edits Or the below answer.

Comment: Checking each result, it appears both come out to give the same conclusion of $y=ax$, though your answer was better in my opinion :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take $log$ on both sides and differentiate w.r.t $x$;

$\frac{m}{x} +\frac{n}{y}. y'=\frac{(m+n)}{(x+y)}. (1+y')$

$\implies y'(\frac{n}{y}-\frac{m+n}{x+y})=\frac{m+n}{x+y}-\frac{m}{x}$

$\implies y'=\frac{y}{x}$ on simplification